# Как создать базу данных на основе модели mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Делаю приложение на [meanio](http://mean.io). Система реализует основу для разработки, просто создает пакет и пишешь свою бизнес логику, тривиальные настройки, как подключение базы данных, шаблонизатор, архитектуру системы делает среда meanio.
Никогда еще сам не создавал базу данных на монго, вот сейчас над этим и застрял.

Написал следующую модель данных:

```
    'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;


/**
 * Order Schema
 */
var OrderSchema = new Schema({
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  client: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Client'
  },
  paymentType: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref:'paymentType',
    required: true
  },
  passenger: [{ 
    type: Schema.ObjectId, 
    ref: 'passenger', 
    required: true 
  }],
  driver: { 
    type: Schema.ObjectId, 
    ref: 'driver', 
    required: true 
  },
  status: { 
    type: Schema.ObjectId, 
    ref: 'status', 
    required: true 
  },
  moment: {
    start: { type : Date, default: Date.now },
    met: { type : Date, default: Date.now },
    end: { type : Date, default: Date.now }
  },
  direction:{
    from: { 
      type: Schema.ObjectId, 
      ref: 'place', 
      required: true 
    },
    to: { 
      type: Schema.ObjectId, 
      ref: 'place'
    }
  },
  sum: {
    type: Number
  },
  km: {
    type: Number
  },
  comment: {
    type: Number
  },
  ticket:{
    type: Number
  },
  permissions: {
    type: Array
  },
  updated: {
    type: Array
  }
});

/**
 * Validations

OrderSchema.path('title').validate(function(title) {
  return !!title;
}, 'Title cannot be blank');

OrderSchema.path('content').validate(function(content) {
  return !!content;
}, 'Content cannot be blank');
 */
/**
 * Statics
 */
OrderSchema.statics.load = function(id, cb) {
  this.findOne({
    _id: id
  }).populate('user', 'name username').exec(cb);
};

mongoose.model('Order', OrderSchema);
```

Далее использую методы контроллера для создания, обновление, чтения и удаления. Вот метод для создания:

```
 create: function(req, res) {
            var order = new Order(req.body);
            order.created = new Date();
            ///...  Указать другие параметры заказа

            order.save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).json({
                        error: 'Cannot save the order'
                    });
                }

                res.json(order);
            });
        },
```

Для создания заказа используется справочники в базе данных и данные которые вводить диспетчер. Как например добавить в заказ клиента, если я еще не создал такую коллекцию клиенты? У меня имеется модель для каждого указанного в моделей.

Есть вариант заранее создать эти справочники в базе данных, но и тут я не понимаю как добавить в базу данных через консоль.

Полная версия JSON файла которая требуется для заказа

```
{
paymentType: 'Tariff',
client: objectId(hfjdhjfhsfr3hbcy84783),
passengers: [
    {
        name: 'Аян',
        phone: '+77775647544'
    },
    {
        name: 'Баян',
        phone: '+77776463392'
    }],
created: 20160118123400,
driver: objectId(hfjdhjfhsfr3hbcy84783),
status: objectId(hfjdhjfhsfr3hbcy84783),
moments: {
    start: 20160118123400,// Время подачи машины к пассажиру
    met: 20160118125023, // Время когда пассажир вышел из дома и сел в машину
    end: 20160118132014 // Время когда пассажир был доставлен на место
},
direction:
    {
        from: 'Гостиница Казахстан',
        to: 'Аэропорт'
    },
sum: 2700,
km: 23,
comment: 'Пассажир с ребенком', 
ticket: '1234567890'
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение было таким. Вроде все понял после наставления и прочтения документации mongoose

фактически тебе не надо ничего делать для создания базы данных и модели данных
потому что монго создает базу автоматически при первом обращении к этой базе: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_create_database.htm
MongoDB use DATABASE_NAME is used to create database. The command will create a new database, if it doesn't exist otherwise it will return the existing database.
команда use неявно используется мангузом при подключении к монго:
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/ test ');
test в данном случае и есть название базы
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html
The first thing we need to do is include mongoose in our project and open a connection to the test database on our locally running instance of MongoDB.
что касается модели данных, монго по большому счету похер на модель, она имеет набор коллекций в каждой базе и также создает коллекцию автоматически

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;


/**
 * Order Schema
 */
var OrderSchema = new Schema({
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
```

это добро нужно только mongoose, который проверяет данные по этой модели
самое важное из того, что стоит указывать в модели - это индексы, вот их мангуз явно создает в монге:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

```
var animalSchema = new Schema({
name: String,
type: String,
tags: { type: [String], index: true } // field level
});
```

все остальное желательно, но не обязательно
mongo - это schemaless database (база без схемы)
поэтому часть своего sql server опыта тебе лучше забыть
в mongo все проще в плане "начать работу"!

я бы посоветовал тебе не торопиться и внимательно почитать little mongo book: http://www.pvsm.ru/download/mongodb-ru.pdf
и документацию по мангузу, это займет пару дней, но зато поймешь что к чему.

По своему опыту скажу, что начать работать с монгой легче, чем с sql server

mongolab помнишь? облачная монга
Там все тебе нужное следано через веб-интерфейс
с ним еще проще начать